# passing a dict with arguments to argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I am using a codebase that expects a large set of argument via command line using argparse library and I neet to call that code inside a loop and inject the arguments via dictionary and not via command line without changing that codebase, I call the code as follow:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser('Training', parents=[get_args_parser()])
args = parser.parse_args()
main(args)
```

Where get_args_parser() is a large list of arguments and defaults such as :

```
def get_args_parser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser('Set transformer detector', add_help=False)
    parser.add_argument('--lr', default=1e-4, type=float)
    parser.add_argument('--lr_backbone', default=1e-5, type=float)
    parser.add_argument('--batch_size', default=2, type=int)
    parser.add_argument('--weight_decay', default=1e-4, type=float)
    parser.add_argument('--epochs', default=300, type=int)
    parser.add_argument('--lr_drop', default=200, type=int)
```

...

If i need to pass a dictionary , as arguments , like:

```
argdict = {'lr_drop':20,'batch_size':5}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Construct a `argparse.Namespace` object from the `dict` and pass that to `main`, rather than using a new parser: `main(argparse.Namespace(**argdict))`.

Comment: For a start do a `print(args)` to see what regular parsing produces.  `vars(args)` shows that `namespace` in dict form.

Comment: You can call the parser with your own `argv` parameter: `args = parser.parse_args(argv)`, but that `argv` has to immitate the `sys.argv[1:]` list that you get from the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using some clues by @Jaser and @chepner , what i did is as follow:

```
args_to_argdict = {'a':1 , 'b':49 ,'c': 'text' }



    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[get_args_parser()])
    args = parser.parse_args()
    arg_dict = vars(args)

    for key,value in args_to_argdict.items():
        arg_dict[key]= value
```

so that the args value change , then i run the main :

```
main(args)
```

with the modified args .

Answer (score 1):

you should use like this:

```
import argparse
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-d", "--dict", required=True, help="Your dict as string", default="{}")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())
argdict = eval(args["dict"])
print(argdict)
# or you cam print some dict specific var
print(argdict["name"]) #Jasar
```

the you can call your file like it:

```
python3 file.py -d '{"name":"Jasar"}'
```